# I cant write int on keyboard(Python)

Tags: python, keyboard

```
import keyboard

start_value=(68)

keyboard.write(start_value)
```

It doesnt work.I dont want to make my start_value string because I need that as a `int` please help me I know it is an easy problem but I am new at this :)

Comment: `keyboard.write(str(start_value))` doesn't change the actual type value of start_value, just what's being sent to the function. Also `(68)` is not an int. it's a tuple that contains a single int 68

Comment: @TheLazyScripter no, it's an `int`, the parentheses are simply redundant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `start_value` equal to a string. Python doesn't necessarily use declarations like other languages. You need to change the `start_value=(68)` to `start_value=("68")` In order to write the number 68. You can use `start_value` though as a variable for the integer.

Comment: why do you still keep the redundant parentheses? also they seem to need it afterwards as an `int`

Comment: I tried but if I do like this I cant do math with it I mean I cant do start_value+1=69 it will be 681 please give me another answer